# Entity Framework 2 columns with many to one

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table with 2 columns and those 2 columns have the reference from one table.

I am using Entity Framework code first but the approach that I have doesn't work when I try to build the migration.

The "parent":

```
public class NodesTree
{
    public NodesTree(){
        this.ActualTreeNode = new List<TreePath>();
        this.NextTreeNode = new List<TreePath>();
    }

    public int TreeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tree Tree { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TreePath> ActualTreeNode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TreePath> NextTreeNode { get; set; }
}
```

The child:

```
public class TreePath
{
    public TreePath()
    {
    }

    public int NodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual NodesTree Node { get; set; }

    public int NextNodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual NodesTree NextNode { get; set; }

    public int TreeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tree Tree { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration I have these definitions:

```
        this.HasRequired( n => n.Node )
            .WithMany( t => t.ActualTreeNode )
            .HasForeignKey( n => n.NodeId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

        this.HasRequired( n => n.NextNode )
            .WithMany( t => t.NextTreeNode )
            .HasForeignKey( n => n.NextNodeId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
```

When I add the migration I got this error:

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that there are incorrectly configured relations in your model. This is not correct:

```
this.HasRequired( n => n.Node )
    .WithMany( t => t.ActualTreeNode )
    .HasForeignKey( n => n.NodeId )
    .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

this.HasRequired( n => n.NextNode )
    .WithMany( t => t.NextTreeNode )
    .HasForeignKey( n => n.NextNodeId )
    .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
```

It should be:

```
this.HasRequired( n => n.Node )
    .WithMany( t => t.ActualTreeNode )
    .HasForeignKey( n => new { n.NodeId, n.NextNodeId })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
```

Because dependent's FK must contain all columns of principal PK. You must also remove navigation property from Three to One.

Comment: Still have the same problem.